# Restore rows from a backup table into another table.

Tags: t-sql

I'd like to do simple delete from EmpTable and then insert into EmpTable Select * xxEmpTablemmddyyy
But EmpTable is being reference by too many tables.

Consider the following business flow :

- Employee Tables, are referenced by many tables thru pk and fk.
- Any update on the employee table (say change in employee name) updates the existing row's effective_end_date and then creates a new row with new effective_start_date
- Information that gets inserted/updated to employee table comes from many source files (foxpro tables, csv files, etc)
- Said source files are then loaded to staging table
- Do some validation
- Stored Procedure spTransfer :
  -- Backup the existing table (Select * into xxEmpTablemmddyyyy from EmpTable)
  -- Update/insert into Employee tables.

Consider the scenario.

- User loads the source files to staging table, did some validation stuff
- Executes the procedure spTransfer
- User realized that source files are incorrect.

Now, I need to bring back the status of EmpTable based on the xxEmpTablemmddyyyy.

I'd like to do simple delete from EmpTable and then insert into EmpTable Select * xxEmpTablemmddyyy
But EmpTable is being reference by too many tables.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Elmer

Comment: If you can't delete from EmpTable because of the foreign key relationships, doesn't this mean that the incorrect data needs to be removed from the other tables as well? I.e., you can't just back out the bad data from EmpTable but from all of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

SO is the requirement to be able to reverse the delete and insert?

save the rows being deleted into an archived table, so create the archived table, if you have an identity field you will have to insert with identity_insert on

```
select * into MyEMpTable_Archived from MyEMpTable
where 1=2;
```

select the rows to be deleted and insert them into the archive table.

Delete the rows from the target table.

Load the new rows from stage table.

You will need to track the newly inserted rows too in case you want to reverse the operation. So record the max value before the load and then again after the load.

IF the user calls after the new data is loaded, it would be possible to delete the newly inserted rows, and put back the deleted rows.

This is a lot of work.

Make sure you have good frequent backups, invest in SQL virtual restore or some other tool that would allow you to retrieve only the one table you are after into a non-production environment and then transfer the desired rows back into the table.

If this happens frequently maybe you should not delete from the target table but have a bit field and mark them as inactive or deleted so you could avoid all this.